# Econometrics: why the i.i.d assumption and weak exogeneity assumption imply strict exogeneity?

Tags: econometrics, regression, applied-econometrics

The proposition is from lecture notes of advanced econometrics of Yongmiao Hong: [image: notes page]

A1: $\{Y_t,X_t'\}_{t=1}^n$ is an i.i.d. random sample.

A2: $E(\varepsilon_t|X_t)=0$ almost surely with $E(\varepsilon_t^2)=\sigma^2<\infty$.

Then A1 and A2 imply the strict exogeneity holds:
\begin{equation}
E(\varepsilon_t|X)=E(\varepsilon_t|X_1,...,X_t,...,X_n)
=E(\varepsilon_t|X_t)=0
\end{equation}
My question is about the second equality: why we have $E(\varepsilon_t|X_1,...,X_t,...,X_n)
=E(\varepsilon_t|X_t)$ under assumptions given above?

Comment: Hi: $\epsilon_t$ is only in the same equation as $X_t$. Therefore, strict exogeneity of $\epsilon_t$ only depends on  $X_t$ and not the $X$'s at other times.

Comment: @mark leeds thanks, it's very intuitive.

Comment: Your comment is apparently valid. You may answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \epsilon_t \vert X \right] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon_t \vert X_1, \dots, X_t, \dots, X_n \right]\\
&= \mathbb{E} [Y_t - X_t'\beta^0 \, \vert X_1, \dots, X_t, \dots, X_n] \\
&= \mathbb{E} [Y_t - X_t'\beta^0 \, \vert X_t] \quad \text{since $\{Y_t,X_t\}$ is iid.} \\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[ \epsilon_t \vert X_t \right] \\
&= 0 \quad \text{by Assumption A2.}
\end{align*}

Comment: Aren't you appealing to Assumption 4.2 in the second line of this proof?

Comment: Got it, thank you so much!

Comment: @HRogers I am indeed, but even if the relationship is non-linear (i.e. $Y_t = g(X_t) + \epsilon_t$), the result would be equivalent.